# Recording from two Webcams simultaneously on one computer

Tags: webcam

I'm trying to set up a simple two-camera interview using two Logitech Webcam Pro 9000 cameras connected via USB to a single Windows Vista machine.

The problem is, Logitech's camera software sees both cameras, and can record video from both cameras, but only one at a time. I have to select one camera or the other, it won't allow me to capture video from both (or even view both) at the same time.

I want each camera to record a separate video file simultaneously, so I can take them both afterwards and edit them into one inter-cut video.

I've been doing web searches looking for anyone else who has had a similar problem, but I'm not finding anyone. I know that home security setups do this sort of thing routinely, so I can't believe it is impossible.

Has anyone ever recorded inputs from two webcams at the same time on a single machine? Does anyone have any tips on how to do it?

Comment: think CCTV software, they can capture multiple cameras simultaneously.

Comment: I think this particular issue is a bug in the logitech driver software.  Maybe you could avoid it by passing one camera through USB to a virtualbox or something...

Answer (score 3):

There is a program called Amcap that comes for free (or at least it did... been several years since I last saw it) with the Microsoft DirectX SDK.

It is a direct interface to all web cams on a system and you can run many instances at once, although you have to manually change the camera setting on each instance - easiest way is to copy the file to different folders as it saves a .ini file with the settings.

I have tried looking for you and I cannot find it anywhere, you may get in luck by downloading the whole SDK, but I cannot guarantee it.

By typing Amcap in to Google, I found [this link](http://amcap.en.softonic.com/), the interface looks identical however this says trial.

I have been looking for the past 10 minutes for you for the original version I am using, but not having much luck so sorry... The last time I saw it would of been the DirectX 9 SDK if that is any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect both to your PC, and like Wil said use Amcap or VirtualDub which will allow two instances to be made, then capture on the individual instances. If your using HD cams make sure they are plugged into two separate USB controllers else they wont work together due to bandwidth issues unless you have USB3 probably work then. Else you can reduce the resolution to 320X240 which reduces the bandwidth of each camera and will allow more than one cam to record on one USB controller, even 640X480 made the bandwidth requirements too much. So either use low a resolution or increase number of USB controllers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use PY software's Active Webcam. Apparently it can capture videos from multiple web cameras simultaneously. It has a very slick interface and is just an awesome software. You can try using it!! I've seen demo version of it!! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I used [iSpyConnect](http://www.ispyconnect.com/) to setup my home "surveillance" with 3 x Logitech C270's. I don't think you'll get 30 fps on all of them but it can record all inputs at once.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there is another way...If you download [Free2XWebcam](http://www.free2x.com/) Recorder, and you have Movenote, Screencast, or a similar application, then you can run multiple videos simultaneously. In order to edit them together, you will need an application like [Shotcut](https://www.shotcut.org/download/) (free) or one of the other more paid products.

One reason you might want to have this capability is to edit in interesting perspectives if you're recording alone, or cut back and forth in editing a skype video interview podcast.

Bottom line - it can be done, and it doesn't need to cost anything more that a little time getting smart on the shotcut software.
~
Cheers