# Using multiple instances of webcam without thirdparty applications in windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, webcam

I want to show my webcam out in an swf file. That is in a webpage. At the same time, i need to record the stream using FFmpeg or Vlc. But the problem is the webcam cant be accessed by two applications at same time. I had read about applications like Manycam, Splitcam. etc. I cant use all this. I want to know is there any opensource solution available?

Also, can i take input to ffmpeg from the swf in the webpage? so that the device wont be disturbed again.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/40715/recording-from-two-webcams-simultaneously-on-one-computer?rq=1

Comment: No it is not a duplicate. My requirement is different.

Comment: We don't do specific product recomendations. `VirtualDub` one of the solutions, suggested in the link possible duplicate, actually is open source.  You don't seem to indicate what requirements are different.  What you want will not be possible without third-party software.  You might consider revising your title.

Comment: I recommend looking at the documentation on the [dshow input device](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow) to use the webcam as input, and the [tee muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee) to simultaneously capture and stream to your currently unknown output protocol.

Comment: tee cant b used since i dnt wanna display and preview at same time. Preview must show always and when i execute record later, then only it has to be recorded.

Comment: FYI @Unnikrishnan if you see a spam answer on a post, please flag it as "spam" instead of "not an answer". The system handles spam flags in a special manner, and content can be automatically deleted if it receives enough spam flags. This also helps the automatic spam filters learn.